# Php script to edit a product

Tags: php

I'm wanting a script to edit a product but I've not been able to write or find a script that will work. I have managed to create script to delete a product from a database which the hosting site is PhpMyAdmin.

```
  <?php      
    function renderForm($id = '', $name = '', $description = '', $genre = '', $price = '', $image = '', $error = '')
     {
     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE HTML >
     <html>
     <head>
     <title>New Product</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <?php 

     if ($error != '')
     {
     echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
     }
     ?> 

      <form action="" method="post">
     <div>
     <strong>id: </strong> <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><br/>
     <strong>name: </strong> <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /><br/>
      <strong>description: </strong> <input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" /><br/>
     <strong>genre: </strong> <input type="text" name="genre" value="<?php echo $genre; ?>" /><br/>
      <strong>price: </strong> <input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" /><br/>
      <strong>image: </strong> <input type="text" name="image" value="<?php echo $image; ?>" /><br/>


                 <th>id</th>
                 <th>name</th>
                 <th>description</th>
                 <th>genre</th>
                 <th>price</th>
                 <th>image</th>


     <p>ALL FIELDS ARE REQUIRED!</p>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
     </div>
      <p><a href='view.php'>Back</a></p>
     </form> 
     </body>
     </html>
     <?php 
     }

     include('connect-db.php');


     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     { 
     // get form data, making sure it is valid
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']));
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']));
    $genre = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['genre']));
    $price = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['price']));
    $image = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['image']));


     // check to make sure the fields are entered
     if ($id == '' || $name == '' ||  $description == '' || $genre == '' || $price == '' || $image == '')
     {
     // generate error message
     $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

     renderForm($id = '', $name = '', $description = '', $genre = '', $price = '', $image = '', $error = '');
     }
     else
     {
     // save the data to the database

     mysql_query("INSERT product SET id='$id', name='$name', description='$description', genre='$genre', price='$price', image='$image'")
     or die(mysql_error()); 

     // once saved, redirect back to the view page
     header("Location: view.php"); 
     }
     }
     else
     {
     renderForm('','','');
     }
    ?>
```

The purpose of the edit script is to save time having to delete a product to and adding it again on the website.

Comment: <form action="" method="post"> need to add an action. like `<form action="" method="post"> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>` Should strongly think about using at least mysqli_ since mysql_ is deprecated. The check for post should be above the html.

Comment: Use Php error reporting and chk errors first and this is not an update statement.

Comment: @devpro By "update", you mean their `INSERT product SET...`? It's valid syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html - Had he used a `WHERE` clause, now that would be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

**Change this:**

```
mysql_query("INSERT product SET id='$id', name='$name', description='$description', genre='$genre', price='$price', image='$image'")
     or die(mysql_error());
```

**To something like this:**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE product SET id='$id', name='$name', description='$description', genre='$genre', price='$price', image='$image' WHERE id='$id'")
     or die(mysql_error());
```